# Convert a Registry BINARY value into meaningful string

Tags: vbscript, registry, binary-data

I'm looking for a way or a Vbscript which can convert a registry key's binary value into a sting.

For example think this is my key:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\System\Majid]
"FilePath"=hex:50,4f,2b,2a,90,93,e0,11,80,01,44,45,53,54,00,00
```

It is translated to: PO+*گ“à€DEST

But what does it mean really? I want to decode this strange value into meaningful word.
If you can give me a simple vbscript which I can replace my key in it and receive the result, I'll really appreciate you a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. Use this bit of code to do your thing.
See how I get the registry value and converts it.

```
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001  
objreg = GetObject("winmgmts:" & _  
      "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _  
      strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")  


objreg.GetBinaryValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "System\Majid", "FilePath", strRetVal  

MsgBox RegBinaryToString(strRetVal)  

function RegBinaryToString(arrValue)  
 strInfo=""  
  for i=0 to ubound(arrValue)  
   if arrValue(i)<>0 then strInfo=strInfo & chr(arrValue(i))  
  next  
 RegBinaryToString=strInfo  
end function
```

Comment: Hi roch, thanks for reply, but where should I put my binary code to convert?

Comment: Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001  
    objreg = GetObject("winmgmts:" & _  
          "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _  
          strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")  


    objreg.GetBinaryValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "System\Majid", "FilePath", strRetVal  

    MsgBox RegBinaryToString(strRetVal)  
  
    function RegBinaryToString(arrValue)  
     strInfo=""  
      for i=0 to ubound(arrValue)  
       if arrValue(i)<>0 then strInfo=strInfo & chr(arrValue(i))  
      next  
     RegBinaryToString=strInfo  
    end function

Comment: Sorry about the code above. Tried to format it but couldnt get that working :~ So I've changed the original answer.

Comment: Hi roch, thanks again, but I will get an error for line 2 char 1 !!! what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
Set objRegistry = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
target = objRegistry.RegRead("HKCU\System\Majid\FilePath")
output = ""
for k = LBound(target,1) To UBound(target,1)
    output = output & chr(eval("&H"& hex(target(k))))
next
msgbox output
```